# My characters face is too bumpy

Tags: modeling

I want to know how i can makemy characters face a bit smoother.

Here is a picture of the object
[image]

mesh in edit mode
[image: Here is the object in edit mode]

Comment: Try to add a subsurface modifier. This will subdivide your mesh and make it smoother.

Comment: Not that kind of bumpy and if i do that the fingers won't be how they are suppose to be

Comment: can you show the inner mesh (edit mode) ?

Comment: yeah here you go

Comment: try selecting some vertices around a bumpy area and smooth them individually with *w* -> *smooth* , use proportional editing and move/scale them a bit, and as a last suggestion you could temporarily switch to sculpt mode and do a click or two with the smooth brush.

Comment: Not helping and i can't just fix it with sculpt mode and if i could fix it by messing with the vertices i would have done so by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the topology of you mesh, no amount of smoothing will completely fix that. 
You should avoid big changes in face size between neighbouring faces (smoothing will help with this) 
Also try and remove all the faces with more than 4 edges, as these can get triangulated in odd ways when displaying the mesh.
Another thing to avoid is vertices with lots of edges attached to them as these can lead to pinching artifacts with smooth shading and also subdivision.

The general rule for modelling faces is to make face loops around each of major features (e.g. they eyes should have rings of faces around them like goggles). See the following image for an example of a face with good topology (taken from blender.org)[image: Blenderella Image from blender.org]

There are a number of tutorials around the net covering best practices for character modelling which would help you, for example:
https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenderella/56040ecf044a2a00a515ada6